# Remove Blank Line In Between Select Queries When Spooling to CSV File

Tags: sql, export-to-csv, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using oracle sql developer in order to spool some data to a csv file.  So far I have this in one file:

```
SET head OFF;
SET echo OFF; 
SET termout OFF; 
SET verify OFF; 
set colsep ,
set pagesize 0
set feedback off
@sandbox.sql
```

Sandbox.sql contains this:

```
spool "C:\TEMP\test.csv"
select 'Date,Average' from dual;
select to_char(rollup_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), average from sample_table
order by 1;
spool off;
```

This produces some csv file that looks like this:

Date    Average

1/1/2012    900 
1/2/2012    910

I want to get rid of the blank line that follows the column headings, but I cannot set trimspool on (option does not exist) and union all fails to work because the data types are not the same.  Does anyone know how to remove that blank line in oracle's sql developer environment?

Comment: http://pregen.wordpress.com/2010/06/17/output-sql-queries-to-csv/ ??
they are speaking about something like
SELECT * FROM CONTACTS
WHERE email = NULL
INTO OUTFILE ‘missingemails.csv’ FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’ LINES TERMINATED BY ‘n’;

But i did'nt try it, let us know the result...

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for, because this is just basic  selection from a table and exporting it into a csv file.  It does not allow me to create column headings <-- I can export the file just fine without headings (no blank lines), but with headings, there becomes a blank line separating the headings and the data.

Comment: Do you have to do the extraction in SQL developer? If you extract to a *nix or even windows command line you can have a script post-process the file. What are you building a flat file for? Loading to another system? Reporting?

Comment: Now that I think about, this is more of a curiousity question than anything.  But yes, in SQL developer.

Answer (score 4):

Use "Set Newpage none" command.

SET NEWP[AGE] {1 | n | NONE}
Sets the number of blank lines to be printed from the top of each page to the top title. A value of zero places a formfeed at the beginning of each page (including the first page) and clears the screen on most terminals. If you set NEWPAGE to NONE, SQL*Plus does not print a blank line or formfeed between the report pages.

Comment: This is the accurate response to the OP.  Oracle will add a line at the top of the output.  The example by the OP showed TWO blank lines.  One, before the header column and the second between the queries.  Using set newpage none fixes both.

Comment: I use sql developer 3.2.20 and even add SET NEWPAGE NONE and then write two sql statement in the sql file, there is a blank line between the two sql query result.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, using SQL Developer (version 18.2)

I don't have your table, but I do have HR.EMPLOYEES.

```
cd c:\sqldev
set feedback off
set pagesize 100
set sqlformat csv
spool so-no-blanks.csv
select 'Date, Average' from dual;
select to_char(hire_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), salary from employees
fetch first 3 rows only;
spool off
```

*-- set sqlformat csv: tells SQL Developer's script engine to automatically return the resultset in a CSV format (json, xml, insert, html, delimited are also available)*

SQL Developer's script engine was updated a few years ago to support pretty much everything SQL*Plus offers, plus a TON more. Like that 'cd' command - it sets the path when doing something like a 'spool'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have just found myself in the same situation as roostersign and I have managed to avoid the blank line between my two queries in SQL*Plus with:

```
set space 0
```

I got there by testing the suggestions here: [SQL*Plus: Formatting query results](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/SP33/ch4.htm#toc029)

Comment: This sets the space between columns (and has been replaced with set colsep)  Column spacing can be important when spooling to CSV files, but is not what the OP asked.